# How can I replace each match group with a new value?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

I am converting my regex macros to convert ligatures from Np++ to Vscode.

In notepad++, my regex was:

pattern : `"(ﬀ)|(ﬃ)|(ﬄ)|(ﬁ)|(ﬂ)|(ﬅ)"`  [or more exactly the html entities `(&#xFB00;)|(&#xFB03;)|(&#xFB04;)|(&#xFB01;)|(&#xFB02;)|(&#xFB05;)`  ]

replace by : `(?1ff)(?2ffi)(?3ffl)(?4fi)(?5fl)(?6ft)`

In VSCode, I am using this [extension](https://github.com/bhughes339/vscode-replacerules) to save an apply my regex. It uses JavaScript regular expressions. I can't find a way to convert the NP++ `replace by`. I could use a `ruleset` that runs several `rules`, one to replace each ligature separately, but I would like to find a way to do it like NP++ did it. Something along this: `($1=ff)($2=ffi)($3=ffl)($4=fi)($5=fl)($6=ft)` which should mean , take `group 1` and replace it by `ff`, take `group 2` and replace it by `ffi`.

The full rules in my VSCode settings.json would be like:

```
"Replace ligature (ﬀ)|(ﬃ)|(ﬄ)|(ﬁ)|(ﬂ)|(ﬅ)": {
    "find": "(ﬀ)|(ﬃ)|(ﬄ)|(ﬁ)|(ﬂ)|(ﬅ)",
    "replace": "($1=ff)($2=ffi)($3=ffl)($4=fi)($5=fl)($6=ft)", //???
},
```

Comment: In general the `$` needs to be escaped if you are looking for a literal dollar

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, the example from the extension doesn't include the `\` before the `$` . When I write `($1=ff)`, I mean : takes the group 1 which is ﬀ and replace it by ff

Comment: Probably also something worth asking on the VS Code issue tracker, as they're the authority on what VS code does/does not support, and whether they'll take a feature request if the latter.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I am not very good at regex so I wanted to make sure that there isn't an easy solution first before asking the extension team.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed that that is the "replace" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following rule will do the trick

```
  "replacerules.rules": {
    "Replace ligatutures": {
      "find": ["ﬀ","ﬃ","ﬄ","ﬁ","ﬂ","ﬅ"],
      "replace": ["ff","ffi","ffl","fi","fl","ft"]
    }
  }
```